# How can I find all the files in use by a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-8.1, services

I have used Process Explorer to do this with processes, but the thing about Windows services is that multiple services run under one process. I need to find where a particular service is executing from and what files are in use by it.

Comment: Multiple services can be run in one svchost.exe process. svchost.exe generally runs system DLL file (sometimes exe), you can see that file in registry details of that service.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and was able to track down the files I was looking for. Thank you for the info!

Comment: Then write your answer with details so that every reader can understand.